# Camunda custom candidate task property

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I am new in Camunda.

Could you please tell me whether it is possible to add custom property 'camunda:candidateUsersReadOnly' something like:

`<bpmn:userTask id="Task_1eqdx5t" name="task name" camunda:candidateUsers="IC754VBA08D5UC93XE,IC754VBA08D5UC93ZC" camunda:candidateUsersReadOnly="IC754VBA08D5UC93XE,IC754VBA08D5UC93ZC">`

and then call getTaskService().getIdentityLinksForTask(taskId) to get ids defined in 'camunda:candidateUsersReadOnly' ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you can't use a custom `camunda:` namespace attribute.  But maybe you could achieve your goal by using extension elements.

You can add them on the "extension" tab of the properties panel in the modeler.

See [Extension Elements](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.12/user-guide/model-api/bpmn-model-api/extension-elements/) for documentation and samples.